# wp_list_pages shortcode jumps above previous content

Tags: shortcode

I have the following shortcode:

```
function roofspan_product_childpages() {
    $list_p = array(
      'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
      'child_of' => '12',
      'title_li' => 'Products: '
    );
    return wp_list_pages( $list_p );
}
add_shortcode( 'product_childpages', 'roofspan_product_childpages' );
```

In a Wordpress page, I have some paragraph content, and in the last paragraph I have the shortcode `[product_childpages]`.

On the front end, the `[product_childpages]` is rendered before the previous text paragraphs.

How can I ensure `[product_childpages]` stays at the end of the page content? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your list is printed immediately.

`wp_list_pages()` has the `echo` parameter, which is `true` by default. Make it false like here:

```
<?php
function roofspan_product_childpages() {
    $list_p = array(
      'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
      'child_of' => '12',
      'title_li' => 'Products: ',
      'echo' => 0 // Note this
    );
    return wp_list_pages( $list_p );
}
add_shortcode( 'product_childpages', 'roofspan_product_childpages' );
```